# Android, to create ui like stack of cards

Tags: android, android-layout

How to create UI that is shown in the image. It is like stack of cards. when user swipe the card from from right to left then it move to the last.
I have not find any api to implement this.

[image]

Comment: `StackView` is the closest thing in the Android SDK.

Comment: You should be able to use CardView and StackView to implement, however I've never dabbled with any of those. Would be a long, hard climb.

Comment: To create it at the bottom of the screen you can use `BottomSheet` from Google support library. To create stack of some views use `StackView`. To create view frame like on picture use `CardView`.